# Framework Search Paths is missing in Search Paths of Build Settings

Tags: ios, xcode10.2

I believe this is something simple but I am kind of struggling with it ... new to iOS development ... I need to add framework search paths in the build settings of my project but for some reason I don't see the "Framework Search Paths" setting in the search paths section ... I am not sure how to activate or enable it or make it visible ... if you guys can point me to the right direction I will grateful to you ... Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please show your entire project window. What is the word you entered to find search path?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please ensure "`All`" is selected at the top bar instead of "`Basic`" / "`Customized`" options.

Comment: This is helpful. But for some reason, the `Framework Search Paths` is appearing under `Customized` option as well for some targets. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just about to get updated with your XCode latest version, I recommend you go check for **Workspace Setting** in **File** menu.

When you see **build settng** is `New Build System`, then try with setting it as `Legacy Build System`.

Hope get helped.